# CSS Borders For a Website

Tags: html, css

Hey I am making a personal website to start displaying my work but have come up with a browser compatibility bug.

I have three containers using the blueprint framework (sidebar, header, and content). The right of the sidebar I have a border and the same for the bottom of the header. The problem is that the border for header is not showing up and I don't know why.

You can see the site and view source code at jaredsmith.se, and as far as I know it only seems to work on Safari but does not appear to work on Chrome and Firefox. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Downvoting this because it was a very simple fix to find and correct, and should have been done before coming here. I suggest you look into usage of FireBug, Chrome Developer Tools, and IE's F12 Developer tools. They all allow you to select an element and view it's CSS. In this case the CSS was even highlighted with a little 'invalid property flag'.

Comment: Validating your document and CSS should always be your first step in debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space after the 2 in "2px". Remove it, and the border will appear.

```
#header {
  border-bottom : 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom : 5%;
}
```

Also, there's a typo in your doctype. This causes IE to use quirks mode.

Change `<DOCTYPE html>` to `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I feel embarrassed for even asking. :/ Thank you for the extra advice as well, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I can't even count the number of times I've been tripped up on some stupid thing like that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `style.css` on line 30:

`border-bottom: 2 px solid black;` is invalid. Change to `border-bottom: 2px solid black;`